# XML parse issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml

I have a XML file in the documents directory that I am trying to parse (to display in a table view).

```
<tickets>
  <ticket>
    <tid>11111</tid>
    <status>Open</status>
    <summary>Summary 1</summary>  //want to grab this
    <notes>Notes 1</notes>
  </ticket>
  <ticket>
    <tid>11112</tid>
    <status>Open</status>
    <summary>Summary 2</summary>  //want to grab this
    <notes>Notes 2</notes>
  </ticket>

  ...

</tickets>
```

I would like `summary` to be displayed in the table view. For now, I am just trying to get a NSMutableArray filled with all of the summary strings.

I am using `XMLReader` to create a dictionary of everything. I then use the following code to try to get to summary.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:save];
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// Parse the XML into a dictionary
NSError *parseError;
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xml error:&parseError];

NSDictionary *ticketsArray = [xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"tickets"];
NSDictionary *ticketArray = [ticketsArray objectForKey:@"ticket"];;
//Now have a dictionary with ticket... what to do next?
```

I'm not sure where to go next. Do you have any idea how to get all of the summaries into a NSMutableArray? I can use something other than `XMLReader` if that is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (NSDictionary *d in ticketArray) {
    NSDictionary *d2 = [d objectForKey:@"summary"];
    [summaries addObject:[d2 objectForKey:@"text"]];
}
```

The strings that you get back for your summary text may need to be trimmed, but the basic idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *summaries = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *key in [ticketArray allKeys])
{
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"summary"]) 
        [summaries addObject:[ticketArray objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Caveat: Written from memory and not tested.
Also, you have a dictionary called ticketArray, this confused me a bit but I've assumed that that actually is a dictionary.